# Flex Layout compilation error for SSR build with Angular Ivy

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout, angular-ivy

I try to upgrade an Angular 8 app to Angular 9 and I'am stuck with an build error under Ubuntu/Debian (Windows works fine):

Im building a SSR-package with the production flag (`ng run app:server --configuration=production`). This is the relevant part of the build log from Gitlab-CI.

```
Compiling @angular/flex-layout/core : main as umd
Compiling @angular/flex-layout/server : main as umd
Compiling @angular/flex-layout/extended : main as umd
Compiling @angular/flex-layout/flex : main as umd
Compiling @angular/flex-layout/grid : main as umd
Compiling @angular/flex-layout : main as umd
Hash: ebebbb435a85a9bde859
 Time: 304615ms
 Built at: 03/02/2020 1:33:20 PM
   Asset      Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
 main.js  1.76 KiB       0  main
 Entrypoint main = main.js
 chunk    {0} main.js (main) 28 bytes [entry] [rendered]
 ERROR in Tried to overwrite /builds/<path>/node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/module.d.ts.__ivy_ngcc_bak with an ngcc back up file, which is disallowed.
```

What I guess whats going on is that Ivy does not get the core module is already compiled and then failes in the `@angular/flex-layout`

All caches have been cleared. It only seems to work on windows. Other computers with Ubuntu or Debian will all fail at the same spot.

Has anyone had a smiliar problem with Angular 9 and Ivy?

Comment: what is your node version? i am using flex layout in Angular 9 in my project and it works fine. My node version is 12.15.0

Comment: I'm using v12.16.1

Comment: i am using ubuntu as well,
here are dev tool versions for angular
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.2",
"@angular/cli": "~9.0.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.1",

Comment: Those are matching my versions.

The only workaround I found so far is: First build the browser module, then build the server module. This seems to work. Building the server module first fails (always coming from a fresh `npm install`)